# Nothing RPROVIDES - python3-adafruit-circuitpython-framebuf - yocto(kirkstone)

Tags: python, runtime-error, yocto, bitbake, yocto-kirkstone

Title:
Bitbake Fails to Build python3-adafruit-circuitpython-framebuf for Custom Raspberry Pi Image

Body:

I'm working on a Yocto Project for the Raspberry Pi 4 and trying to include the pi-racer package in my custom image. However, when I run bitbake for my custom image, I encounter the following error:

```
ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'python3-adafruit-circuitpython-framebuf' (but ~/../../../../recipes-core/images/custom-rpi-image.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
NOTE: Runtime target 'python3-adafruit-circuitpython-framebuf' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['python3-adafruit-circuitpython-framebuf']
ERROR: Required build target 'team2-rpi-image' has no buildable providers.
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['custom-rpi-image', 'python3-adafruit-circuitpython-framebuf']
```

Here is the recipe I'm using for adafruit-circuitpython-framebuf:

```
SUMMARY = "CircuitPython framebuf module, based on the Python framebuf module."
HOMEPAGE = ""
AUTHOR = "<Adafruit Industries <circuitpython@adafruit.com>>"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=6ad4a8854b39ad474755ef1aea813bac"

SRC_URI = "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7f/ae/3efed2f5a1827370d979823982a0b2137aae7bead9121354aa14354b6fcc/adafruit-circuitpython-framebuf-1.6.5.tar.gz"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "7fbb799093fd578bc3b82a60f64af453"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "d0c71d123606a8ef18f0e1093bee28b93a70fa0baf2461c86ce644f09c8d3272"

S = "${WORKDIR}/adafruit-circuitpython-framebuf-1.6.5"

RDEPENDS_${PN} = " \
    python3-adafruit-blinka \
    python3-core \
"

inherit setuptools3
```

I have added this package in custom-rpi-image.bbappend, but it doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure why the package cannot be found or why it's deemed unbuildable. Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue or where to look for potential problems?